# What is this symbol ``, and why can't some people see it?

Tags: unicode, symbols, line-endings

The symbol is this one: ``

It crops up at the end of folder names sometimes on our filesystem.  The people who put the folder there swear that they couldn't see it.  I think it might be being produced by one of our internal asset building tools, perhaps in response to something copied in from a Google docs spreadsheet?

Sorry that's so vague...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This symbol is used by OS X if you add a trailing space to a folder name on a FAT file system.

Why? Because it is forbidden to have trailing spaces in folder names on Windows. As OS X allows trailing spaces in general, it somewhat extends this behavior to FAT drives. The private use unicode character is used as a means to keep the file system sane at the same time.

While you're on the Mac, you barely see the additional character as it is rendered as space there. Only after moving the drive to Windows or Linux, the weird unicode character shows up as unprintable.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the culprit could be Windows `CHKDSK` (analogous to `fsck`) …

https://github.com/dw/scratch/blob/master/ntfs-3g-chkdsk-unicode-fix.py →

```
# … Windows
# CHKDSK, which will immediately replace all the invalid characters with
# Unicode ordinals in the private use plane.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the unicode character `U+F028` which falls in the [private use area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) of `U+E000`–`U+F8FF`. This means it's use is application specific. You are probably right that some tool produces this character and fails to remove/replace that character when copying. Wikipedia lists some [vendor usage examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas#Vendor_use) but I doubt that this list will help much.

To find the cause of the problem, I would first try asking the users who created the folders about which operating systems they use and which applications they copied the text from. If you think one of your build tool is the cause, you could try to search for that character in all log files of those tools and any databases that the tools use.

As for the actual question in the title, this character does not have a defined symbol. Some applications show a default symbol while other application may just ignore it and show nothing.